# Xcode push workspace with submodules wrong repository on push

Tags: ios, xcode, git, git-submodules, workspace

I am trying to cleanup my workspace. I've created a separate reusable static library for the helper functions and another for the main project.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
SimplyStats/
    SimplyStats/
    externals/GoodStuffIOS
```

both the main project and the library project have been succesfully pushed/updated/committed to their respective bitBucket repositories.

But when i use XCode to push changes, i get the following dialog:

[image: Source Control Push Dialog]

Notice that the Remote repository for the GoodStuffIOS project is at fault. The repository Organiser shows that the repositories are set up correctly. Whatever I do, I cannot fix that remote. How do I fix this?

EDIT: Here are the contents of my .git/config (starred the repo names)

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = false
[branch "master"]
[remote "SimplyStats"]
    url = https://************@bitbucket.org/**********/simplystats
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/SimplyStats/*
[submodule "externals/GoodStuffIOS"]
    url = https://************@bitbucket.org/**********/goodstuffios.git
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what i had to do to fix the problem.

- Close the workspaces,
- Go to Organiser/Repositories,
- then for each relevant project, select in left column and remove by clicking '-'
- quit XCode
- verify/clean .git/config
- verify/clean .gitmodules
- reopen XCode
- open workspace

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the source folders, find the `.git` folder and navigate into it. There is a `config` file and that contains the urls of the remote repositories:

It should contain something like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = <remote-repo-url>
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

Verify, if it has the correct url. Try a `git clone <remote-repo-url>` in some temp folder.